# keda func deploy from a dir which contains spaces is failing

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools, keda

I am using Visual Code with Azure Core Tools to deploy a container to a K8S cluster which has KEDA installed. But seeing this docker error. The error is caused because the docker build is run without the double quotes.

```
$ func kubernetes deploy --name bollaservicebusfunc --registry sbolladockerhub --python
Running 'docker build -t sbolladockerhub/bollaservicebusfunc C:\Users\20835918\work\welcome to space'....done
Error running docker build -t sbolladockerhub/bollaservicebusfunc C:\Users\20835918\work\welcome to space.
output: 

"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile


(.venv)
20835918@CROC1LWPF1S99JJ MINGW64 ~/work/welcome to space (master)
```

I know there is a known bug [Spaces in directory](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1299)

But posting to see if there is a workaround, this is important as I have eveything in Onedrive - Comapny Name and it has spaces in it

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the [code for `func`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/blob/dev/src/Azure.Functions.Cli/Actions/KubernetesActions/KubernetesDeployAction.cs), you could specify `--image-name` instead of `--registry` which seems to skip building the container.

You would have to build your docker container manually using the same code shown in the output and provide the value for the `-t` argument of the `docker` command for `--image-name` of the `func` command after.

Also, since this would not push your docker container as well, make sure to push it before running the `func` command.